# How to pass a parent component from child component in Mat dialog and maintain the state of the whole component after the dialog was closed

Tags: angular, angular-material

I know how to open a component in mat dialog in angular. But I want to retain the state of the whole component when the dialog is closed. What I mean is I want the changes I have done in dialog to be reflected in the actual component.
If I could avoid using matdialog.afterClosed that would be great.